# How to limit the user to check only certains checkbox in a list (based on his previous check)

Tags: jquery, checkbox

i have a list of checkboxes that have an incremental list of value.

i need to apply those rules :

1. the user can check 1 checkbox min to 3 checkboxes max
2. the user can only check contiguous checkboxes

(example :

- the user checks the #6,
- then only #5 or #7 are available,
- the user checks the #7
- then only #5 or #8 are available.
- the user checks #8,
- then no more checkboxes are available !

i have this list of checkboxes :

```
<form id="time-slot" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="tranche" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tranche" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tranche" value="3" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tranche" value="4" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tranche" value="5" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tranche" value="6" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tranche" value="7" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tranche" value="8" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tranche" value="9" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tranche" value="10" />

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

how could i handle those rules with jquery ?
thx for your help !

Comment: what about #6,#7,#8 if #6 is checked, or #4,#5,#6 if #6 is checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#time-slot input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    // Disable all unchecked
    $('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').attr('disabled','disabled');
    // If 3 are checked we are done
    if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 3)
        return;

    // If the checkbox either side of this one is checked, we only have 1 option
    if($(this).prev().is(':checked') && $(this).next().is(':checked')){
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        return;
    }

    // Enable the checkboxes before and after the current selection
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').prev().removeAttr('disabled');
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').next().removeAttr('disabled');

    // If none are checked, enable all
    if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0)
        $('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

this should cover all eventualities. See it in action here...
http://jsfiddle.net/JcCdD/

*UPDATE*

The difference here is that we have to use prevAll and nextAll to skip over br and label elements. As these work slightly differently when using a collection of elements, we have to break it into an each statement.

```
$("#time-slot input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    // Disable all unchecked
    $('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').attr('disabled','disabled');
    // If 3 are checked we are done
    if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 3)
        return;

    // If the checkbox either side of this one is checked, we only have 1 option
    if($(this).prevAll('input').first().is(':checked') && $(this).nextAll('input').first().is(':checked')){
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        return;
    }

    // Enable the checkboxes before and after the current selection
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
        $(this).prevAll('input').first().removeAttr('disabled');
        $(this).nextAll('input').first().removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    // If none are checked, enable all
    if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0)
        $('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

new example here... http://jsfiddle.net/bEjTf/

Comment: it's working like a charm :) thx for your help ! my breakfast will be soooooo peacefull !!!!

Comment: WOW and you don t work with the value attribute... and as my needs have changed and my value is no more incremental... it still work :D can i validate twice ? :D

Comment: hi dean, i simplified my HTML for the example but i need to insert a <label> tag after each <input>. so the .next() or .prev() function doesn't work anymore...see this example : http://jsfiddle.net/5S4hG/8/

Comment: i tried .next('input[type=checkbox]') OR .prev('input[type=checkbox]') but it doesn't work ! :'(

Comment: Ok, this gets a bit more complicated, but is still achievable. See my update above and the jsfiddle example here... http://jsfiddle.net/bEjTf/

Answer (score 0):

Hook into the `onchange` event of the limiting checkbox, setting the `disabled` attribute of the checkboxes that are now unavailable if the user just checked the box, unsetting the attribute otherwise. Illustrative example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ch1').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#ch2").attr('disabled','disabled');
        } else {
            $("#ch2").removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Also, see [this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/urdh/9gy3c/). Obviously, this needs adapting for your specific situation, particularly when it comes to checking what boxes to enable/disable in every situation, but I get the feeling that that's not your problem.

Comment: i didn't thought about this .change() event !

Answer (score 0):

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j9MJF/1/

```
$("#time-slot input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    var me = $(this);
    var clickedIndex= me.prevAll().length;
    var totalChecked = $("#time-slot input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;

    $("#time-slot input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        var myIndex = $(this).prevAll().length;
        if(!$(this).is(":checked")) $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        if(totalChecked < 3) {
            if(myIndex == clickedIndex
               || $("#time-slot input[type='checkbox']").eq(myIndex+1).is(":checked")
               || $("#time-slot input[type='checkbox']").eq(myIndex-1).is(":checked") ) {
                $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Unticking doesnt quite work here. Tick box 2,3 and 4, then untick box 2. box 1 is now enabled but it shouldn't be.

Comment: I think the general idea was shown but you're right there was an issue with the unchecking.  The update has been posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:

```
$("#time-slot").submit(function(){
   var $checks = $(this).find(":checkbox");  
   if($checks.size() > 3) { alert("Max 3 checked checks allowed"); return false;}
   if($checks.size() == 0) { alert("Check at least one!"); return false;}
   var prevCheckedIndex == null;
   var contiguous = true;;
   $checks.each(function(i, elem){ 
        if(!$(this).is(":checked")) return;
        if(prevCheckedIndex != null && prevCheckedIndex != i-1)
            return (contiguous = false);         
        prevCheckedIndex = i;
   });
   if(!contiguous) { alert("Checked boxes must be coniguous!") return false;}
});
```

This will trigger on form submit, but validates all the conditions you want.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: sorry i didn't specifiy that i need to handle this with the onclick event... but i'll keep this in my toolbox ;)